# hosting a github pages server with multiple html files

Tags: html, github, github-pages, shared-hosting

Im trying to host a github live server for a project that right now has a "index.html" main folder with 4 files inside that main folder named "forgot-pass.html" "home.html" "sign-in.html" "sign-up.html"

I know to host on github your html needs to be a index.html but my question is can you have a folder named index.html with html files inside that folder and it still work? or how can i host on github if i have multiple html files named various things.

Comment: Please elaborate on "can you have a folder named index.html with html files inside that folder and it still work?" Also, how do we get from html files to sass? How do you see things aren't working?

Comment: for you to host on a github live server it specifies in the docs your html must be named index.html so my question is since i have multiple html files in my project can i just put them in one folder named "index.html" and it should work on github live server. Or no you cannot have a folder with html files inside it for github hosting.

Comment: What is a "*GitHub live server*"? I'm having trouble finding that terminology in GitHub's documentation or any other official source. Mind providing a link? My understanding is that GitHub's repository-based hosting feature does not support anything remotely resembling `live-server` or anything more dynamic than client-sided JavaScript. As such you'll have to preprocess your SASS and other nonstandard markup before committing/uploading it to your GitHub Pages repository.

Comment: in other words...Github pages site

Comment: And why do you need a folder with name "index.html" ? What's wrong with just the 5 files  in the root? (please edit the question instead of a comment, that's easier to read for others)

Comment: Please make sure this isn't a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its required to have a "index.html" file located in the root directory. As far as having a main FOLDER named index.html with files inside of that as-well, did not work for me. but i did not try to have a index.html file in the root directory on its own ALONG with a separate folder containing the rest of the html files. So i don't know if that works or not. i just put all the html files in the root directory and made sure to have one named "index.html"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have more html files in the same folder or subfolders, but it's mandatory to have the "index.html" file. Also I think you can make that folder but will not work (I don't know if it works or not, but give it a shot).